# Android: Verify device google account name on server

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm developing an android app which uses google account available on device to authenticate user to server-side component.

I send google account name (gmail address) to server but to be able to verify it with google on server, I request an oauth token on android device and send it to server as well.

The problem is that although I don't need access to additional user info, I have to use oauth email scope which opens a confirmation dialog. I don't like this dialog because I'm going to verify account name not accessing user info.

<strike>There is also `AccountManager.getPassword(account)` but I don't like to communicate or use user password.</strike>

It is also possible to use WebView and authenticating user like a web app (using OpenId for example) but it doesn't seems an optimal solution on a device.

Is there any other/better way to verify device account name on server?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to verify user accout name without login(account name+pass). 
In any way you are using oAuth(first time login), or direct login - you have to use pair (login+pass).
I have newer seen answer from any auth service like incorrect password for login "xxx".

Comment: This article might be helpful: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?m=1

Comment: @mjn Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Feel free to add it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article gives a detailed - with source code - description of the verification process:

[Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html?m=1) by Tim Bray

> Short version: You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through
>   Google Play services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You
>   send the token to your back end and your back end can use it to
>   quickly and cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the
>   app.

With the information in this article it was easy for me to implement client- and server side Android and JavaEE code.

Answer (score 3):

Use AccountManager or Google Play Services to get an OAuth2 token for the user profile (scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile). Then verify it using the Google endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo) and optionally get user info. A sample app is provided here: http://oauthssodemo.appspot.com. You seem to be doing something similar, and if so this is the right (or at least recommended) way to do it. 
BTW, you cannot get the user password, because you are not signed with the same certificate as the account provider.

The only other (reliable) way to do this is to send the user an email to their GMail address with a random token and have them enter it in the app. This lets you verify that they have access to the email, so it must be theirs (unless of course they stole someone else's device).

Or you can simply trust that if the user has the account registered on their device, it it indeed their account, because they authenticated at least once when activating the device. Then you just use the Gmail address as is, which may or may not be sufficient for your app.

Comment: thanks I'm already doing what you are advising (as you have also advised in another answer). The problem is that it's possible to call server-side api from anywhere and I have to verify account claims before accepting them. It's also possible to use GCM to verify each device but then a rooted device can fake an account.

Comment: Verifying a real token is the only reliable thing then (that I know of).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to verify Google accounts without a valid token. You might want to refer to the official Android documentation below.

http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/index.html

Comment: Do not be too dogmatic, is it impossible to login with password? :))

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it. The authorization of Google Account on the server side requires a valid oauth token.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this:

- On device

  1. Select an account (get the email address)
  2. Request an OAuth token
- Send the email + token to the server
- On server

  1. Use Google's API to retrieve basic user info from the token
  2. Compare the email address returned by google with the one received

Comment: What you ask for is not possible, and this should be the way to go.